Does Apple's new Password Manager work with 2FA QR codes?
Today I use Dashlane's family plan, which suits me well, but it comes with a cost.
I read in the announcement that Apple's password manager supports QR codes, which makes me understand that it's possible to add 2FA to it, just like Dashlane does.
However, when interacting with the UI, I didn't find any clear option to have 2FA/MFA in it.
Which, nowadays, is kind of useless since many sites require 2FA.

Feedback about beta software should be sent directly to Apple.

On which build are you testing? The current settings app runs time based codes well. Did you check there?

It is a beta what exists now will not be the same as released - especially if your reasoning in the last paragraph is correct

Maybe you're looking for the verification code option in the initial form for adding a new password. You would have to create the password first, then go into it after saving and you should see the option to add a verification code. There's a screenshot at the top of this Mashable article that shows it. Functionally it looks like the same behaviour as the existing Settings app in Ventura/Sonoma.

In the macOS Settings app (I've seen this in both Sonoma and Ventura), when you tap in to set up a verification code, you can paste in a setup key OR you can choose a QR code image OR you can just control click on the QR code (possibly limited to Safari). I'm guessing it's similar in the new app, maybe even better. Of course, on an iPhone/iPad you can just scan the QR code with the built-in camera.

(this screenshot is from Sonoma's Settings app, but the new password manager's version of this probably looks pretty similar)

This includes guesses pleas only answer things that you can cite or know from your own knowledge.

They are reasonable assumptions based on the fact that the password manager, which is in beta, is mostly just a port of the existing functionality with some aesthetic changes. And I showed a screenshot of the new design which confirms that.

It worked, I have to first add the password/account and then I was able to add MFA/2FA and Passkeys.
